# How to make text go on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[this is text that overlaps itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfsKF.jpg)

I am currently trying to use a flex box with columns made the height of the first column 100% so that it would force the other two boxes to be on top of each other. In the first box I typed artistry by and in the second and third I’m trying to align the text so that they can have LE and XI directly over each other. Any advice here would help.

Comment: use a defined width and wrap with flex ....

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code? You may be missing some containers so you can have better control. **I haven't tested this**, but this example might guide you.

HTML:

```
<div class="logoContainer">
   <h1> artistry by </h1>

   <div class="rightSideOfLogo">
       <h1>LE</h1>
       <h1>XI</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logoContainer {
  display: flex,
  flex-direction: row
}

.rightSideOfLogo {
  display: flex,
  flex-direction: column
}
```

Comment: No need to write flex-direction: row; for logoContainer. It takes row value by default.